# Widget Kit Info plist file can't be found

Tags: xcode, widget, info-plist

I finished work on a widget in my app then I just moved the all widget folder from groupe folder to another (to organize folders) then when I try to build the app the following error showed in Xcode, please anyone can help to fix this issue or I shall remove the widget from the app and start over again.

The error

"error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/.../WidgetName/Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'WidgetNameExtension' from project 'AppName')"

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?  I have checked my Build Settings and I am getting this exact error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the **Info.plist File path under Build Settings** of your Target ?

I assume the path has changed after your folder restructuring.